# Inserting data in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have 5 input fields, When user fill those 5 fields and hit on submit, we need to store those in database

For this I have this code in my controller

```
public function send()
{
$this->loadmodel('Invitefriend');
$this->request->is('post');
$this->Invitefriend->create();
$this->loadModel('Student');
$id =  $this->userValue['Student']['id'];
$contact = $this->userValue['Student']['phone'];
$emails= $this->data['Invitefriends'];
$currentDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentDate));
$email_count = count($emails);
for($i=1;$i<=$email_count;$i++)
{
$email = $emails['email'.$i];
$this->Invitefriend->save(array("ref_student_id"=>$id, "ref_contact"=>$contact, 'email'=>$email, 'date'=>$currentDate));
}
}
```

With is inserting only last field value into database, But I need to store all the 5 fields into database. is there any thing wrong in my code.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
// save multiple or all records
$this->Invitefriend->saveAll() 
or 
$this->Invitefriend->saveMany()
```

instead of

```
Invitefriend->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Create entity for table...
$invTable = $this->Invitefriend->newEntity();

//Build db table fields...
$invTable->ref_student_id = $id;
$invTable->ref_contact = $contact;
$invTable->email = $email;
$invTable->date = $currentDate;

//Store data into table...
$this->Invitefriend->save($invTable);
```

You function look like:

```
public function send() {
    $this->loadmodel('Invitefriend');
    $this->request->is('post');
    $this->Invitefriend->create();
    $this->loadModel('Student');
    $id =  $this->userValue['Student']['id'];
    $contact = $this->userValue['Student']['phone'];
    $emails= $this->data['Invitefriends'];
    $currentDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentDate));
    $email_count = count($emails);

    //Create entity for table...
    $invTable = $this->Invitefriend->newEntity();

    //Build db table fields...
    $invTable->ref_student_id = $id;
    $invTable->ref_contact = $contact;
    $invTable->date = $currentDate;

    for($i=1;$i<=$email_count;$i++) {

        $invTable->email = $emails['email'.$i];

        //Store data into table...
        $this->Invitefriend->save($invTable);
    }
}
```